# Facebook Like Plugin HTML Entities

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, special-characters, html-entities

I installed the new Like plugin on my Wordpress blog. I also have the Open Graph Plugin for Wordpress installed.

It all works magically except that the HTML special characters are showing on my Facebook Wall when I click like.

I tried preventing the Open Graph plugin from encoding the content of the mega tag in the first place by editing the php for the plugin.

I changed:

```
return "<meta property=\"{$property}\" content=\"".htmlentities($content)."\" />";
```

to:

```
return "<meta property=\"{$property}\" content=\"".$content."\" />";
```

and then tried:

```
return "<meta property=\"{$property}\" content=\"".htmlspecialchars_decode($content)."\" />";
```

But no luck

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of output that get’s interpreted incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise removing the HTML encoding of the content variable, use [esc_html()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Text_Nodes).

The problem is either in Facebook's own Like plugin, or the WordPress one (i.e. taking data from the source, modifying it, and saving it).

Which *exact* WordPress plugin are you using for Like?

Comment: Thanks for the response here is where I found the WP Like Plugin: http://willfults.com/facebook-like-wordpres/

As far as I can tell from the php in the plugin, it's only configuring and positioning the like component from Facebook. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you're running this? I'm a bit stumped by the problem!